# how to delete multiple items with checkbox in ionic 3

Tags: checkbox, ionic3

I would like to know how to delete multiple items from the list in Ionic 3, using CheckBox, here is my code, in the delete () function I do not know how to only exclude the products that are checked with the checkbox. I thought that this would work but did not delete anything . If anyone can help me, thank you.

produto.html

```
<ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let produto of produtos">
      <ion-item>
        <input [(ngModel)]="modelo[produto.id]" value="{{produto.id}}" name="modelo" type="checkbox" ng-checked="produto.checked">{{produto.id}}
        <h1> {{ produto.barra }}</h1>
        <h3> {{ produto.deposito_nome }}</h3>
        <h3> {{ produto.quantidade }}</h3>
        <!--<h2 class="price">{{ produto.preco | currency:'BRL':true }}</h2> -->
      </ion-item>

    </ion-item-sliding>
  </ion-list>
  <button ion-button (click)="excluir()">Excluir Todos</button>


import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { DatabaseProvider } from '../../providers/database/database';
import { SQLiteObject } from '@ionic-native/sqlite';
import { NavController, NavParams, ToastController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { InventarioProvider, Product } from '../../providers/inventario/inventario';
import { RestProvider } from '../../providers/rest/rest';
import { HomePage } from '../home/home';


@Component({

  selector: 'page-inventario',
  templateUrl: 'inventario.html',
})
export class InventarioPage {

    produtos: any[] = [];
      modelo: any[] = [];

    this.model = new Product();

        if (this.navParams.data.id) {
          this.inventarioProvider.get(this.navParams.data.id)
            .then((result: any) => {
              this.model = result;
            })
        }
      }
      ionViewDidEnter() {
        this.getAllProdutos();
      }

      getAllProdutos() {
        this.inventarioProvider.getAll()
          .then((result: any[]) => {
            this.produtos = result;
          });
      }

      excluir() {
         this.produtos.forEach(function (produto) {
  if (produto.checked) {
    this.modelo[produto.id] = produto.checked;
    return this.dbProvider.getDB()
      .then((db: SQLiteObject) => {
        let sql = 'delete from inventario where id = ?';
        let data = [produto.id];
        return db.executeSql(sql, data)
      })
  }
})
```

}
         }

Comment: so do you want to delete the items from the list and from db?

Comment: I want to delete the items marked with bd's checkbox

Answer (score 0):

Hey I never worked with SQlite but assuming the other parts of your code work including the db handling, you need to do something like the below in your delete method:

```
excluir() {
    // create comma separated list of products to be deleted from db:
    const toBeDeleted = this.produtos.filter(produto => produto.checked === true);
    // now execute db script to delete multiple products:
    return this.dbProvider.getDB().then((db: SQLiteObject) => {
        // here i might be wrong but you should be able to delete all items with ids in one operation, don't use loop as it may get expensive:
        db.delete("inventario", "id IN (?)", toBeDeleted.join())
        db.close()
    }).then(() => {
        // now do the modelo step (not sure what is this though in your case):
        toBeDeleted.forEach(produto => {
            this.modelo[produto.id] = produto.checked;
        })
        // finally update product array by filtering out deleted items:
        this.produtos = this.produtos.filter(produto => produto.checked === false);
    })
}
```

Please note I am not entirely sure how you use delete multiple items using SQlite, but I hope you know that part. I think you might need to do this way:

```
db.delete("inventario", "id IN (" + toBeDeleted.join() + ")", null)
```